# How to send <n> requests (instead of sending for duration <d> seconds)

Tags: wrk

Current wrk configuration allows sending continuous requests for  seconds (duration parameter).

Is there a way to use wrk to send  requests and then exit.

My use case: I want to create large number of threads + connections (e.g. 1000 threads with 100 connections per thread) and send  instantaneous bursts towards the server.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with LUA script:

```lua
local counter = 1

function response()
   if counter == 100 then
      wrk.thread:stop()
   end
   counter = counter + 1
end
```

Pass this script with `-s` command line parameter.

Comment: Where would you write this script?

Comment: Put the code to any file and pass it to the `wrk` after -s parameter.

Comment: This does not stop wrk itself. It keeps on running until it reaches the duration you specified with `-d`

Answer (score 1):

I make changes to wrk to introduce new knobs. Let me know if anyone is interested in the patch and I could post it.

I added a -r to send exactly  requests and bail out.

Comment: Hi, I'm interested in this. Could you post this patch, if you still have the code?

Answer (score 1):

Artem,

I have this code-change in my fork:

https://github.com/bhakta0007/wrk